# How can I use a the result of document.documentElement.clientwidth in a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications

I am trying to scale my existing site to be more responsive using HTML5 and CSS3. But the problem I am having here is that I want to use a PHP `include` to control what shows on the website using the JavaScript `document.documentElement.clientwidth` property in a PHP conditional statement. Example:

```
<?php 
  if (document.documentElement.clientwidth < 640) {
    include "mobile_sidebar.php";
  }
  else include "mainsite_sidebar.php";
```

So, the responsive design isn't just document reflow but an actual reduction in the content in a mobile phone scenerio for example.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't combine JS and PHP like that - the PHP is run before the JS is even rendered!  You need to pass the client data back to the server AFTER the page is loaded, then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass some javascript data to a PHP script via AJAX on page load, and then send some data back to render the page accordingly.  Maybe show a splash page while PHP is processing and returning data?